Something wrong in reversing a linked list recursively
I'm trying to solve a code challenge that asks to reverse a linked list. Given is a pointer to the head node.
Here is my attempt:
struct ListNode* reverseList(struct ListNode* head) {
    if(head==NULL || head->next==NULL) return head;
    struct ListNode* p=reverseList(head->next);
    p->next=head;
    return head;
}

When I dry run, it seems to work fine. But when I submit the code to be tested, a time-limit exceeded (TLE) error occurs.
Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong?

p->next=head; makes no sense at all. p is the reversed list (excluding the head) and you want to set the next item of that list to the head?

Clearly if you are going to reverse a list at some point you have to set head->next to null since it will now be the last item in the reversed list. Your code does not do that.

the check makes sense, the recursive call too.
but the lines after are incorrect.
I recommend dry running it with a simple case, three nodes, and working on it line by line (drawing the stack frames even) to try and find the problem.

Learning programming on a path made from steps that work equally well for C and C++ is narrow and twisted. It will be valuable and non-trivial to learn the differences later. But for now better decide on one of the two languages and learn much more easily.

Are you supposed to use a recursive function? Otherwise the TLE could be explained by a loop over the list being much faster, and the expected solution.

Are you using C or C++? You should only use both tags if the question is about something like a comparison between them. Otherwise, tag with the specific language you're using.

There are two distinct problems with your reverse function:

It will introduce a cycle in the linked list when it has more than one node. This means that if there is code that doesn't expect a cycle, and just naively iterates through all nodes of the resulting list, it will get into an infinite loop. This could explain the time limit error you get.

It returns the original head of the list. Instead, it should return the tail of the original list, as that will be the first node of the reversed list.


Let's take a simple example of a linked list with just two nodes, with values 1 and two. Then when reverseList is called, we can visualise the state like this:
 head
  ↓
┌────────────┐     ┌────────────┐
│ val: 1     │     │ val: 2     │
│ next: ──────────►│ next: NULL │
└────────────┘     └────────────┘ 

Then we have a recursive call where as argument a reference to the second node is passed. Inside that recursive call, this pointer is head. I'll call it head' (with apostrophe) here:
 head               head'
  ↓                  ↓
┌────────────┐     ┌────────────┐
│ val: 1     │     │ val: 2     │
│ next: ──────────►│ next: NULL │
└────────────┘     └────────────┘ 

Here we hit the base case and so the recursive call returns the reference to the second node, which in the calling context is assigned to p:
 head                p
  ↓                  ↓
┌────────────┐     ┌────────────┐
│ val: 1     │     │ val: 2     │
│ next: ──────────►│ next: NULL │
└────────────┘     └────────────┘ 

Then p->next=head is executed, and we get:
     head                p
      ↓                  ↓
    ┌────────────┐     ┌────────────┐
    │ val: 1     │     │ val: 2     │
 ┌─►│ next: ──────────►│ next: ─┐   │
 │  └────────────┘     └────────│───┘ 
 └──────────────────────────────┘

A cycle is created. And now, as return head is executed, we see the two problems occur: the wrong node reference is returned, and the cycle is not broken.
The following adapted code corrects both issues:
struct ListNode* reverseList(struct ListNode* head) {
    if (head == NULL || head->next == NULL) return head;
    struct ListNode* newHead = reverseList(head->next);
    // The tail of the recursively reversed list is at head->next.
    //    Append the current node (head) at that tail
    head->next->next = head;
    // And terminate the list at the new tail:
    head->next = NULL;
    // Return the new head, not the old head
    return newHead;
}

